# Find two factors for right shift

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Community,

Assume we have a random integer which is in the range Int32.MinValue - Int32.MaxValue.
I'd like find two numbers which result in this integer when calculated together using the right shift operator.

An example :

If the input value is `123456` two possible output values could be `2022703104` and `14`, because `2022703104 >> 14 == 123456`

Here is my attempt:

```
 private static int[] DetermineShr(int input)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[2];

            if (input == 0)
            {
                arr[0] = 0;
                arr[1] = 0;
                return arr;
            }

            int a = (int)Math.Log(int.MaxValue / Math.Abs(input), 2);
            int b = (int)(input * Math.Pow(2, a));
            arr[0] = a;
            arr[1] = b;
            return arr;
        }
```

However for some negativ values it doesn't work, the output won't result in a correct calculation.

And for very small input values such as `-2147483648` its throwing an exception :

[image]

How can I modify my function so it will produce a valid output for all input values between `Int32.MinValue` and `Int32.MaxValue` ?

Comment: You should get an overflow at 2,147,483,648 too...

Comment: Have you researched what "two's complement" means?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's compare

```
     123456     == 11110001001000000
  ‭   2022703104 == 1111000100100000000000000000000‬
```

can you see the pattern? If you're given `shift` (`14` in your case) the answer is

```
 (123456 << shift) + any number in [0..2 ** (shift-1)] range
```

however, on large values left shift can result in *integer overflow*; if `shift` is small (less than `32`) I suggest using `long`:

```
  private static long Factor(int source, int shift) {
    unchecked {
      // (uint): we want bits, not two complement
      long value = (uint) source;

      return value << shift;
    }
  }
```

Test:

```
   int a = -1;
   long b = Factor(-1, 3);

   Console.WriteLine(a);
   Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(a, 2));
   Console.WriteLine(b);
   Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(b, 2))
```

will return

```
   -1
   ‭11111111111111111111111111111111
   34359738360
   ‭11111111111111111111111111111111000‬
```

please, notice, that *negative* integers being *two's complements*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

are, in fact, quite large when treated as *unsigned* integers